# Return value from USING statement

Tags: c#, .net, return, idisposable, using

Originally this method returns **false** only in case of ANY problems regardless of their type. I'm wondering will applying `using` statement break the logic if exception

Is it ok to return **true** value from the using statement in this manner:

```
    try
    {

        Measurements.DeleteAllMeasurements(ID);
        string query = "DELETE FROM `Narz` WHERE `NAZk_1_ID`=@NAZ_ID";
        using(OleDbConnection strukturaConnection = new OleDbConnection(CommonConnectionString + DbPath + strStructureMdb))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, strukturaConnection);)
                    {

                        command.Parameters.Add("@NAZ_ID", OleDbType.Numeric, 50);
                        command.Parameters["@NAZ_ID"].Value = ID;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return true; 
                    } 
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex);
        return false;
    }
```

Or I should return **false** in another way?

Comment: The **using** does not break your code in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the using statement does is implicitly call the instance's implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose()` at the end of the code block.

Unless you are returning a reference and the `Dispose()` method happens to manipulate it, then the two concerns are completely unrelated.

In short, it doesn't matter what value you return from within a using statement.

***Edit:** About what your method "should return": We don't have enough information to know this.  We don't even know what the name of the method is.  And we don't know by what other objects or aspects of the application the method will be used.  The return value should be meaningful to its caller, and effectively communicate the result of the operation.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead create a bool value when method creates. Inside try set its value to true and in catch set its value to false. Outside catch return that variable value.

Using will have no affect on your code or mine. It is just for calling `IDisposable.Dispose()` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

that'll be fine - all its doing is calling the dispose method of the IDisposable object in the using statement parentheses